# Strange redirection effect with raw_input

Tags: python

According to the [manual](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input), `raw_input` writes to stdout. I have this little program (`test_raw_input.py`):

```
# Test if rawinput writes to stdout or stderr
raw_input('This is my prompt > ')
```

And no matter how I run this:

```
$ python test_raw_input.py > xxx
```

or

```
$ python test_raw_input.py 2> xxx
```

The prompt always ends up in `xxx`. Why is this happening?

Comment: FYI, it will be written to stdout if you redirect both stdout and stderr `python test_raw_input.py > xxx 2> yyy`.

Comment: Exactly, that is my point. `>` is stdout, `2>` is stderr. The manual says raw_input writes to stdout, so only the first version should put the prompt in `xxx`. The second version, using `2>`, should show the prompt in the terminal, since stdout is not redirected to `xxx`. But this is not the case: even when *only* redirecting stderr, the prompt is put into `xxx`. Why?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From your response to KennyTM I gather you understand

```
python test_raw_input.py > xxx
```

and it's only the second usage that you don't understand:

```
python test_raw_input.py 2> xxx
```

I think you are running into the behavior described here http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2008-January/076446.html, which resulted in bug report http://bugs.python.org/issue1927, which has a comment saying it wasn't fixed yet last september.

However, there is a workaround: from https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/chennaipy/R_VJYNdel-o, if you

```
import readline
```

before using `raw_input`, the behavior will be as you expect.

Comment: Thanks, that's interesting. This begs the question: if raw_input is (incorrectly) outputting to stderr, why does the stdout redirection also work? That's why I titled the question "strange effect", because it seems that raw_input redirects to *either* stdout or stderr, but I do not understand exactly how this works.

Comment: Good point. The shell redirections are visible to the Python interpreter, so they can influence the behavior of the code. I haven't looked at the C, but I'm guessing the code behaves differently depending on whether stdout or stderr has been redirected. 

It may useful to add this to the bug report: the people handling the issue may not be aware of this behavior.